# Updating Date/Time value in an SQL Server table from Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date

From Oracle, via a DBLINK, I am trying to update the value in a date field in an MS-SQL Server database.

However when I run this query

```
update axp@mis
SET "ExpireDate" = '2013-06-04 12:00:00'
WHERE "IdNumber" = 103;
```

I get the message:

```
[Error] Execution (13: 16): ORA-28534: Heterogeneous Services preprocessing error
```

I have also tried

```
update axp@mis
SET "ExpireDate" = to_date('2013-06-04 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS')
WHERE "IdNumber" = 103;
```

and I get the message:

```
[Error] Execution (14: 1): ORA-02070: database MISDOORACCESS does not support TO_NUMBER in this context
```

Can anyone advise how I can perform this update from Oracle?

Comment: Can you `SELECT` from the table, i.e. are you sure that the dblink itself is configured and working correctly? Have you tried assigning the value to an Oracle `date` variable and updating using it (to avoid date formatting issues)? And what versions of Oracle and SQL Server do you have?

Comment: I believe there was a network problem which, when fixed, also fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the CAST function. Try this:

```
declare
     v_date date:=to_date('2013-06-04 12:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI:SS');
begin
     update axp@mis set "ExpireDate"=cast(v_date as date) WHERE "IdNumber" = 103;
     commit;
end;
```